# Tablix , Paper Layout Direction

Tags: reporting-services

what is the best Solution to change tablix layoutdirection at run time ?

I want to Swap column order cuse iam using tow language in my report (Arabic , English ) , i want to sawap Tablix layout direction from LTR to RTL at Run time , cuse in this prop i can't write expression

Comment: Deleted my earlier answer, as it was based on a misunderstanding of the issue (which is that the LayoutDirection property of a tablix cannot have an expression entered - it can only be hardcoded to either LTR or RTL).

Answer (score 1):

New answer: I suggest having *two* tablixes, identical except for the LayoutDirection property (LTR on one, RTL on the other) and for the Visibility>Hidden property, which would be an expression based on a parameter value - something like `=IIf(Parameters!RTL.Value="T",True,False)` for the LTR Tablix, and vice versa for the RTL Tablix.

Answer (score 0):

First i read the RDLC as XML
and then update this XML in run time

```
private static void UpdateTableLayoutDirection(string tableId, bool isRTL, XmlDocument doc)
    {
        var tableNode = ReportUtilities.FindFirstNodeByName(doc.DocumentElement, tableId);
        if (tableNode != null)
        {
            string layoutAttName = "LayoutDirection";
            XmlAttribute attribute = tableNode.Attributes[layoutAttName];
            string rtlValue = isRTL ? "LTR" : "RTL";
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                // Update the attribute value (replace with your logic)
                attribute.Value = rtlValue;
            }
            else
            {

                // Replace "456" with the desired default value for the attribute
                XmlAttribute newAttribute = doc.CreateAttribute(layoutAttName);
                newAttribute.Value = rtlValue;

                // Add the attribute to the node
                tableNode.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
            }
        }
    }
```

tableId is Tablix
the idea is to find LayoutDirection attribute and update it;s value then load RDLC Report from XML definition
and this how to load Report From XML

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                doc.Save(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
                localReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
//enter code here
}
```